# Real height of the page (all content), JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

This question isn't here and this is not duplicate.

I need real page (full) height, not only visible part, but scrolled part included.
I try:

```
$('body/html').height(), window.height, window.outerHeight
```

and others, but they give me only the visible height of the page. I want all height.

I work with:

```
html, body { height: 100%;},
```

With many contents and scroll in the page and page with long content.
How can I get full height of the page ?

Comment: $(document).height(), and actually this is a duplicate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery `$('html').outerHeight()` is what you want. The window height is only the height of the viewport. The only way the above wouldn't work is if your `html` is constrained to the height of the window and you have some other wrapping div with an overflow, in which case you'd want to get its `outerHeight()`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using:
document.body.scrollHeight